# Premium-Data Google Places

Tags: google-places-api

I have found the following interesting text at Google .

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details?hl=de#PremiumData

For me, the point type is interesting :

type is the name of the evaluated aspect . Example : atmosphere , service , food , overall impression , etc.

How can I apply this? Unfortunately I have no support found and the German Hotline has no plan :(

Can someone please help ?

Answer (score 0):

Premium Data (also known as Zagat) is deprecated as of May 2, 2016 and will only continue working until May 2, 2017. Since after this time, Zagat ratings and reviews (what you are looking for) will no longer be available there is no point building any solutions around it.

If you want to still know about about it you can use [this form](https://developers.google.com/maps/contact-sales/) to contact sales.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the answer. So it makes no sense to use it, or where it can be only up to 2017 continue to be used